# IdFtp how to display or launch all types of files

Tags: delphi, indy

Without the use of FTP, to launch (or execute) any file, I use: *ShellExecute*.
Now, with the use of the *Indy* components: *IdFtp* , reading a file on my FTP Server, I use Get ().
My question: is there a possibility (with *IdFtp*) to display files of any extension like MSWord, MSExcel, Autocad, ...? , in others words: launch for example *MSWord* on my PC to read a file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: At first,You should store the file in temp folder and then open it by commands like `shellexecute`

Comment: You can't execute a file using FTP. FTP is for transferring files.